# Is there a algorithm for search an element in sorted array excluding one specified number with complexity O(lgn)?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

Let

```
int arr[]={0,1,2,-1,4,8,9,-1,17,32,56,128};
```

the array is sorted excluding a specified number `-1`,and I want to search an element(which is not the specified number) in the array.So is there any algorithm satisfied the following conditions?

1. The time complexity is O(lgN)
2. If the element do not exists in the array,return the the appropriate insertion position.
3. Regard the specified number as a empty slot,the return value can be the position of specified number.

e.g. If I want to search 10 in the previous array,then the return value will be 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the practical use for this? Why would you have an array that's sorted except for one element?

Comment: @Barmar homework assignment/interview/programming competition

Comment: @SalvadorDali Obviously, but I want the OP to admit it.

Comment: @Barmar oh, this will never happen. The best you can hope is 'my friend recently asked me' type of answer.

Comment: @Barmar it's for programming competition

Comment: Do we get the win if we give you the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, just look at the array of length `n`, where all the numbers are `-1` (your specified number). Now randomly select one position and substitute it with some other number. Basically your array looks like this:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Now there is no way you can deterministically find the position of your number 8 using `O(log N)` elements.

---

So **no, in general case you can't do this**. But if the number of specified elements is really tiny, I believe that you can modify binary search to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you can afford O(N) extra storage, and an O(N) pre-processing step.

If you can, you can create an index of the meaningful elements (e.g., an array of pointers to the elements that aren't -1). That takes O(N) time/space, but once you have it, you can use if for a search of the real collection with O(log n) complexity, just like if you didn't have the "dead" entries at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You will only add the complexity to search for -1, that will be less than O(log n).

You can use another array to map the position of -1 in the previous array.